# How to trigger a callback when a boolean flag gets set using Kivy Clock?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, kivy

I have some code running on a separate thread and my main GUI thread depends on that code. I've made a boolean flag to mark the job as done, but I can't come up with a way to call a function when that flag gets set.

Something like that blocks the main thread and the application freezes, which is what I want to avoid:

```
while not flag:
    pass
callback()
```

Using calls like `Clock.idle()` or `Clock.usleep(1)` instead of `pass` also didn't work. Is there something in Kivy like `Clock.schedule_once` that accepts a flag, checks it on every event loop iteration and calls the callback once it's `True`?

**EDIT**
This is where the flag gets set, part of Class 1:

```
async def prepare(self):
    # heavy computations...
    self.flag = True
```

And here's Class 2, the `kivy.app.App` subclass, which has an object property of Class 1 and checks its `flag` property in a loop:

```
def action(self):
    # start the `prepare` method here
    while not self.obj.flag:
        pass
    proceed()
```

Comment: You could create a callback that you pass as an argument of your thread. Once the thread is called, it's sets a the boolean and your main thread is regularly checking the flag. Why not just give the callback to the thread ?

Comment: @iFlo Because once the flag is set, the working function should return to proceed with the events on the loop. It is a callback, so it can't call the function I want (that function also spawns a callback, so before it's called, all the callbacks should finish)

Comment: can you show the code where the flag is set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this where the flag is set.:

```
def prepare(self):
    # heavy computations...
    self.flag = True
    YourAppClass.startClock()
```

And in your App class, something like this:

```
YourAppClass(App):

    def startClock(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.myCallback,0) # run clock thread next frame

    def myCallback(self,dt):
        # do something
```